# Weird bug in python project

Tags: python, debugging

I'm working on a big project in Python, and I've run into a bizarre error I can't explain. In one of my classes, I have a private method being called during instantiation:

```
def _convertIndex(self, dimInd, dimName):
    '''Private function that converts numbers to numbers and non-integers using 
    the subclass\'s convertIndex.'''
    print dimInd, ' is dimInd'
    try:
        return int(dimName)
    except:
        if dimName == '*':
            return 0
        else:
            print self.param.sets, ' is self.param.sets'
            print type(self.param.sets), ' is the type of self.param.sets'
            print self.param.sets[dimInd], ' is the param at dimind'
            return self.param.sets[dimInd].value(dimName)
```

What it's printing out:

```
0  is dimInd
[<coremcs.SymbolicSet.SymbolicSet object at 0x10618ad90>]  is self.param.sets
<type 'list'>  is the type of self.param.sets
<SymbolicSet BAZ=['baz1', 'baz2', 'baz3', 'baz4']>  is the param at dimind
======================================================================
ERROR: testParameterSet (GtapTest.TestGtapParameter)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/ilucmc/gtapmcs/test/GtapTest.py", line 116, in testParameterSet
pset = ParameterSet(prmFile, dstFile, GtapParameter)
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/ilucmc/coremcs/ParameterSet.py", line 103, in __init__
self.distroDict, corrDefs = AbsBaseDistro.readFile(distFile, self.paramDict)
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/ilucmc/coremcs/Distro.py", line 359, in readFile
distro = cls.parseDistro(param, target, distroType, args)
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/ilucmc/coremcs/Distro.py", line 301, in parseDistro
return cls(param, target, distro, dim_names, argDict)
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/ilucmc/coremcs/Distro.py", line 150, in __init__
self.dim_indxs = list(starmap(self._convertIndex, enumerate(dim_names)))  # convert to numeric values and save in dim_indxs
File "/Users/myuser/Documents/workspace/ilucmc/coremcs/Distro.py", line 194, in _convertIndex
print self.param.sets[dimInd], ' is the param at dimind'
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Obviously this isn't the code for the whole class, but it represents something that I don't understand. The error is coming when I index into self.param.sets. Apparently, dimInd is out of range. the problem is, dimInd is 0, and self.param.sets is a list of length 1 (as shown from the print statements), so why can't I index into it?

EDIT: For what it's worth, the `__init__` method looks like this:

```
'''
Stores a definitions of a distribution to be applied to a header variable.
See the file setup/gtap/DistroDoc.txt for the details.
'''
def __init__(self, param, target, distType, dim_names, argDict):
    self.name = param.name
    self.dim_names = dim_names
    self.dim_indxs = []
    self.target = target.lower() if target else None
    self.distType = distType.lower() if distType else None
    self.rv = None
    self.argDict = {}
    self.modifier = defaultdict(lambda: None)
    self.param = param

    # Separate args into modifiers and distribution arguments
    for k, v in argDict.iteritems():
        if k[0] == '_':  # modifiers start with underscore
            self.modifier[k] = v
        else:
            self.argDict[k] = v  # distribution arguments do not have underscore

    if self.target == 'index':
        print dim_names
        self.dim_indxs = list(starmap(self._convertIndex, enumerate(dim_names)))  # convert to numeric values and save in dim_indxs

    if distType == 'discrete':
        entries = self.modifier['_entries']
        if not entries:
            raise DistributionSpecError("Not enough arguments given to discrete distribution.")
        modDict = {k[1:]: float(v) for k, v in self.modifier.iteritems() if k[1:] in getOptionalArgs(DiscreteDist.__init__)}
        self.rv = DiscreteDist(entries, **modDict)
        return
    sig = DistroGen.signature(distType, self.argDict.keys())
    gen = DistroGen.generator(sig)

    if gen is None:
        raise DistributionSpecError("Unknown distribution signature %s" % str(sig))

    self.rv = gen.makeRV(self.argDict)  # generate a frozen RV with the specified arguments
    self.isFactor = gen.isFactor
```

Comment: You'll have to show at least the `__init__` code to know what's going on.

Comment: The reason that I didn't show the __init__ code is that there's a bunch of irrelevant stuff in there that I think confuses the issue. The point is that __init__ calls this method with the arguments 0 and 'baz1', for dimInd and dimName respectively. The code throws an error on the last print statement, but still manages to print it out. Does that make a little more sense? I'd really like to avoid putting the whole massive class in here. I could put some print statements in _convertIndex to show that it's really getting the arguments I think it is.

Comment: Couldn't it be executing the print statements and throwing the error in different tests? I can't see any other reason.

Comment: The problem is if that were the case, then wouldn't the first few print statements show up and not the last one?

Comment: calling methods in `__init__` can get tangled up if there are attributes initialized *after* the method calls.  Don't worry about irrelevant code: show us the `__init__`.

Comment: That's true, but it looks like self.param.sets is initialized correctly, based on my print statements. Regardless of whether it's correct or not, it's a list of length greater than 0, and my index into it is 0, so I don't understand why it's giving me an index error.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is all running through a unittest. Commenting out the other unittests caused more stuff to be printed that's actually leading me to the source of error. I think the unittests were executed in different threads, so the stuff printed out wasn't in order.